# Binding TreeView children to ko.observables

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am working on a basic tree view that will list a few items, and I want to be able to alter the text of the child item based upon a user input.

view:

```
<div class="treeviewUI">
 <p>
   Test Tree View Model
 </p>
 <p><strong>Enter Child One: <input data-bind="value: $parent.childOne"/></strong> <!-- also tried just childOne -->
 </p>
 <ul id='treeMenu' data-bind="foreach: menu">
  <li>
     <div data-bind="click: function() {$parent.toggle($data)}">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.text></span>
        <ul data-bind="visible: $data.expanded,
                       foreach: {data: $data.children, as 'child' }">
          <li data-bind="text:child.text"/>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

and the viewmodel:

```
define([knockout'], function (ko) {

   var childOne = ko.observable();
   var viewModel = {
     menu: [
             text: "Item 1",
                children: [
                    { text: childOne() },
                    { text: "child 1b" }
                ],
                expanded: ko.observable(false)
            },
            {
                text: "Item 2",
                children: [
                    { text: "child 2a" },
                    { text: "child 2b" }
                ],
                expanded: ko.observable(false)
            }
    ],
    toggle: function(node) {
        node.expanded(!node.expanded());
    }
};

return viewModel;

});
```

However, entering input for the `childOne` does not update the treeView subitems.  Am I missing a binding or just using the wrong type of binding.  Or is there something more complicated going on here?

**JSFIDDLE LINK:** http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7GS/54/

Comment: Your fiddle has console errors - Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/raw/master/jquery.tmpl.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing `text: childOne()` you are asigning the value of the `childOne` observable and not the function itself.

So your `text` will contain `undefined` and not the `ko.observable`, you can fix this with removing the `()`:

```
children: [
   { text: childOne },
   { text: "child 1b" }
],
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G82jv/).

Comment: Having a little trouble successfully implementing the solution outside of `JSFiddle`, but that speaks more to something in the background interfering.  Marking as the answer since it will work right once I get the rest of my environment in order.

Comment: Probably you will need to include childone in the root of on your viewModel as well so something like `var childOne = ko.observable();
   var viewModel = { childOne : childOne, 
     menu: [ text: "Item 1",
                children: [
                    { text: childOne },
                    { text: "child 1b" }
                 ], }`